# Getting total in while statement with UNION query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, while-loop, union

I am trying to calculate how much a user has earned so it reflects on the users home page so they know how much their referrals have earned.

This is the code I have.

```
$get_ref_stats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `referral` = '".$user_info['username']."'");
$total_cash = 0;
    while($ref_stats = $get_ref_stats->fetch_assoc()){
        $get_ref_cash = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `completed` WHERE `user` = '".$ref_stats['username']."' UNION SELECT * FROM `completed_repeat` WHERE `user` = '".$ref_stats['username']."'");
        $countr_cash = $get_ref_cash->fetch_assoc();
        $total_cash += $countr_cash['cash'];
        $countr_c_rate = $setting_info['ref_rate'] * 0.01;
        $total_cash = $total_cash * $countr_c_rate;
    }
```

It worked fine when I just had

```
$get_ref_cash = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `completed` WHERE `user` = '".$ref_stats['username']."'");
```

but as soon as I added in the `UNION` it no longer calculated correctly.
For example, there is 1 entry in `completed` and 1 entry in `completed_repeat` both of these entries have a `cash` entry of 0.75. The variable for `$countr_c_rate` is 0.10 so `$total_cash` should equal 0.15 but instead it displays as 0.075 with and without the `UNION` it acts as if it is not counting from the other table as well.

I hope this makes sense as I wasn't sure how to explain the issue, but I am very unsure what I have done wrong here.

Comment: How many entries are there in `members` table ? I am assuming 1.

Comment: @mohkhan yes there is only 1 in the members table, for now atleast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second query instead of `UNION` you should use `UNION ALL` since `UNION` eliminates duplicates in the resultset. That is why you get `0.075` instead of `0.15`.

Now, instead of hitting your database multiple times from client code you better calculate your cash total in one query.

It might be inaccurate without seeing your table structures and sample data but this query might look like this

```sql
SELECT SUM(cash) cash_total
  FROM
(
    SELECT c.cash 
      FROM completed c JOIN members m
        ON c.user = m.username
     WHERE m.referral = ?
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT r.cash 
      FROM completed_repeat r JOIN members m
        ON r.user = m.username
     WHERE m.referral = ?
) q
```

Without prepared statements your php code then might look like

```php
$sql = "SELECT SUM(cash) cash_total
  FROM
(
    SELECT c.cash
      FROM completed c JOIN members m
        ON c.user = m.username
     WHERE m.referral = '$user_info['username']'
     UNION ALL 
    SELECT r.cash 
      FROM completed_repeat r JOIN members m
        ON r.user = m.username
     WHERE m.referral = '$user_info['username']'
) q";

$result = $db->query($sql);
if(!$result) {
    die($db->error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
if ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $total_cash = $row['cash_total'] * $setting_info['ref_rate'];
}
```

*On a side note: make use of **[prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)** in `mysqli` instead of building queries with concatenation. It's vulnerable for sql-injections.*

Comment: Thanks for that! I forgot it took out duplicates.

Comment: and how would I call this? I am sorry I don't use `UNION` a lot, nor do I use huge queries like this so I am not sure how I would use this. Also I know about prepared statements but my host is a **** and won't update the server to allow them. But they can't inject it if there is no `REQUESTS` made by them.

Comment: This is what I am getting when using this code `Column 'cash' in field list is ambiguous`

Comment: @kira See updated answer. If you edit your question and add sample data (one or two rows that represent your example) it'll be possible to get you an exact query.

Comment: The updated answer worked for me, I really thank you for your help, and thank you so much for going beyond my question to help me better the script!

Answer (score 1):

With `$countr_cash = $get_ref_cash->fetch_assoc();` you only fetch the first row of your result. However, if you use UNION, you get in your case two rows.

Therefore, you need to iterate over all rows in order to get all values.

Comment: So I need to make `$countr_cash = $get_ref_cash->fetch_assoc();` a while statement instead... if so I feel like a total moron now because I should have noticed this myself!!

Comment: Or do I need to make a whole new call for each different table?

Comment: Yes, that should fix your problem. Just do it in a loop. You could do it with a different query directly in the query as well.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, So there is only one row in `members` table. You are iterating only once on the members table. Then you are trying to get rows using UNION clause which will result in two rows and not one. Then you are just getting the `cash` column of the first row and adding it to the `$total_cash` variable.

What you need to do is iterate over the results obtained by executing the UNION query and add the `$total_cash` variable. That would give you the required result.

```
$get_ref_stats = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE `referral` =  '".$user_info['username']."'");

$total_cash = 0;
while($ref_stats = $get_ref_stats->fetch_assoc()){
    $get_ref_cash = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `completed` WHERE `user` = '".$ref_stats['username']."' UNION SELECT * FROM `completed_repeat` WHERE `user` = '".$ref_stats['username']."'");
    while($countr_cash = $get_ref_cash->fetch_assoc()){
        $total_cash += $countr_cash['cash'];
    }
    $countr_c_rate = $setting_info['ref_rate'] * 0.01;
    $total_cash = $total_cash * $countr_c_rate;
}
```

Comment: Ok, I got that now I think I have more of a problem, now that I have that done it is showing 0.0825 for `total_cash` when it should be o.15 cause 0.75 * 2 is 1.50 and 10% of that is 15, I am not sure if `$total_cash` is getting confused or if I have messed something way up, but my code is yours exactly right now, so I think I cannot this method to get the sum that I need?